# How to call a function from a chain of module.exports in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've declared a function in one of my models (`review`) and exported it in the standard node way so other files can use it. I then reference it another model (`company`) and export it there as well.

Finally, I'm trying to use the function defined in `company` in another file (`companiesRoute`) but I'm getting a `company.getAllCompaniesWithReviews is not a function` error.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

```
// review.js
module.exports.getAllCompaniesWithReviews = function(next) {
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...
};

// company.js
var reviews = require('./review');
module.exports.getAllCompaniesWithReviews = reviews.getAllCompaniesWithReviews;

// companiesRoute.js
var company = require('../models/company');
company.getAllCompaniesWithReviews(function(err, result) {
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...
});
```

If I try and call the function directly from `companiesRoute` then it works:

```
review.getAllCompaniesWithReviews(function(err, result) {
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...
});
```

This is, of course, the *answer*. But why doesn't my version work?

Also, node v4.4.4.

Comment: You see outside only what you exported. Post your whole files and you will get solution.

Comment: Just do `exports.getAllCompaniesWithReviews = ...` to add new exported properties. Only use `module.exports` when you're replacing the entire exported object.

Comment: @MattHarrison `exports` is just an alias to `module.exports` and it makes no difference. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: It starts out as a reference to the same object but you can change that. Important to know the difference: `exports.something = 'hello'; module.exports = { something: 'world' }; console.log(exports.something); // logs 'hello' not 'world'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this in company.js?

```
module.exports.getAllCompaniesWithReviews = function(next) { 
     reviews.getAllCompaniesWithReviews(next);
}
```

Comment: Nice one. That worked perfectly. What version of node did you try this on? They must changed something in v5 as it works fine in v5 and v6.

Comment: my version is v4.4.2. I need to upgrade it as well. thanks for informing me.